# Add a Reference compiled with another version of Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a procedure written in vb.net with VS 2005 
I'd like add a reference but this is done with Vs 2015.
Is this possible ? 
I have tried but when i add the reference this appare with an exclamation point.

Comment: The VS version is irrelevant because it's a compiled DLL you're referencing.  What matters is the .NET version.  You just need to compile the DLL against the same .NET version that the application will be compiled against. If you need multiple versions of your DLL then so be it.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you